# Unable to import javax.sql.Connection in groovy script and unable to run groovy within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy, m2eclipse

1. How can I import javax.sql.Connection in a Groovy script?
2. How can I configure m2e to work in eclipse

I have a dependency on a jar file I created which uses classes with javax.sql.Connection
and I can call those classes but if I attempt to directly import as in

> import javax.sql.Connection

I get

> Groovy:unable to resolve class javax.sql.Connection

I realize that there is a Sql class in groovy but I have a lot classes I could call that require a connection and I can't figure out how to get imports to work.

Although I can create an executable uber jar with the following pom, I can't configure the project in Eclipse to quit complaining.  Every "fix" I see on stackoverflow that makes it stop complaining in Eclipse stops it from producing an uber jar.

## pom.xml

> xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
> [http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd%22%3E)
> 4.0.0
> org.myproject
> core-groovy-2
> 1.0-SNAPSHOT
> core-groovy-2
> jar
>
> ```
>       <parent>
>       <groupId>org.myproject.</groupId>
>       <artifactId>myproject-pom</artifactId>
>       <version>22.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   </parent>
>   <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
>           <artifactId>myproject-core</artifactId>
>           <version>${org.myproject.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
>           <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
>           <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
>           <version>${logback.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
>           <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
>           <version>${groovy.version}</version>
>           <type>pom</type>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
>           <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
>           <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
>           <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
>           <version>${spock-core.version}</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.github.groovy-wslite</groupId>
>           <artifactId>groovy-wslite</artifactId>
>           <version>${groovy-wslite.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>   <build>
>       <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/groovy</scriptSourceDirectory>
>       <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
>               <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
>               <version>${groovy.compiler.version}</version>
>               <extensions>true</extensions>
>           </plugin>
>           <plugin>
>               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>${compiler.plugin.version}</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
>                   <source>${java.version}</source>
>                   <target>${java.version}</target>
>               </configuration>
>               <dependencies>
>                   <dependency>
>                       <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
>                       <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
>                       <version>${groovy.compiler.version}</version>
>                   </dependency>
>                   <dependency>
>                       <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
>                       <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
>                       <version>3.0.8-01</version>
>                   </dependency>
>               </dependencies>
>           </plugin>
>           <plugin>
>               <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
>               <dependencies>
>                   <dependency>
>                       <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
>                       <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
>
>                   <version>${junit-platform-surefire-provider.version}</version>
>                   </dependency>
>               </dependencies>
>               <executions>
>                   <execution>
>                       <id>junit5</id>
>                       <goals>
>                           <goal>integration-test</goal>
>                           <goal>verify</goal>
>                       </goals>
>                       <configuration>
>                           <includes>
>                               <include>**/*Test5.java</include>
>                           </includes>
>                       </configuration>
>                   </execution>
>               </executions>
>           </plugin>
>           <plugin>
>               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>               <configuration>
>                   <useFile>false</useFile>
>                   <includes>
>                       <include>**/*Test.java</include>
>                       <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
>                   </includes>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>           <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin: needed to run the jar through command line -->
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>${assembly.plugin.version}</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <!-- get all project dependencies -->
>                   <descriptorRefs>
>                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>                   </descriptorRefs>
>                   <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
>                   <archive>
>                       <manifest>
>                           <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
>                       </manifest>
>                   </archive>
>               </configuration>
>               <executions>
>                   <execution>
>                       <id>make-assembly</id>
>                       <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
>                       <phase>package</phase>
>                       <goals>
>                           <goal>single</goal>
>                       </goals>
>                   </execution>
>               </executions>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>       <pluginManagement>
>        <plugins>
>            <plugin>
>                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
>                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
>               <version>1.0.0</version> 
>                <configuration>
>                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
>                        <pluginExecutions>
>                            <pluginExecution>
>                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
>                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>                                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
>                               <!--    <version>${groovy.compiler.version}</evrsion> -->
>                                    <goals>
>                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
>                                        <goal>compile</goal>
>                                    </goals>
>                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
>                                <action>
>                                    <execute />
>                                </action>
>                            </pluginExecution>
>                        </pluginExecutions>
>                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
>                </configuration>
>            </plugin>
>        </plugins>
>    </pluginManagement>
>   </build>
>   <repositories>
>       <repository>
>           <id>central</id>
>           <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
>       </repository>
>   </repositories>
>   <properties>
>
>   <junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>1.3.2</junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>
>       <junit-platform.version>1.8.2</junit-platform.version>
>
>   <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M4</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
>       <hsqldb.version>2.4.0</hsqldb.version>
>       <spock-core.version>2.2.M1-groovy-4.0</spock-core.version>
>       <groovy-wslite.version>1.1.3</groovy-wslite.version>
>       <groovy.version>3.0.8</groovy.version>
>       <assembly.plugin.version>3.1.0</assembly.plugin.version>
>       <compiler.plugin.version>3.7.0</compiler.plugin.version>
>       <groovy.compiler.version>3.7.0</groovy.compiler.version>
>
>   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>       <hsqldb.version>2.4.0</hsqldb.version>
>       <spock-core.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock-core.version>
>       <commons-lang3.version>3.9</commons-lang3.version>
>       <java.version>14</java.version>
>       <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
>       <groovy.version>3.0.10</groovy.version>
>       <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.6</gmavenplus-plugin.version>   
>   </properties>      </project>
>
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle 
> configuration:  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile   
> (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)  pom.xml /vinyl  line 91 
> Maven Project        Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
> ```

Comment: Are you sure you need javax.sql.Connection? Because if I remember correctly it belongs to java enterprise edition world...

Comment: I have classes that take a javax.sql.Connection as an argument.

I can get a Connection with "conn  = ((DataSource )ds.getConnection and it works and javax.sql.DataSource can be imported.

Comment: what is the full stacktrace of the error when you are trying to import connection? usually it contains the reason.